# Resource-Target of pod erroneously needing Swift Version set

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

After successfully linting and updating a pod, I updated it in the main project. However, upon cleaning I encountered this issue:

[image]

Normally this is simple to resolve (go to Build Settings and set the Swift Language Version -- however, this error is occurring on the Resource-Target, which doesn't have that setting...making it very strange that I am running into this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to resolve this.

The Resource-Target includes a `xcdatamodel`. I needed to change the `Code Generation` to `Objective-C` rather than `Swift`. This was hard to find especially since the pod lint step did not catch this or give any warning.

I found this answer via: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7950 -- even though this issue doesn't seem to be exactly the same as this one, but it is related.